# Driver 440 with Xubuntu : ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, xubuntu, nvidia-settings

My computer is : laptop MSI GS75 Stealth (buy in 2019) - With 1 disk 512 GB SSD - 16 GB RAM DDR4 - Intel core i7.

Coming from Windows, I'm trying to upgrade to Linux (I am PHP / Laravel developer).

I recently installed Xubuntu in Dual Boot, and my computer is making a lot of noise, and I do not have this noise with my Windows 10.

I also installed the same Xubuntu on an old laptop that I have (a DELL 1st price, which does not have Nvidia), and on this PC Xubuntu runs well and the fan does not make any noise. So there is a chance for my MSI that it comes from my graphics card.

On my PC I installed the 440 driver of Nvidia by doing this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
```

I then checked the Nvidia 440 driver in "Additional drivers", and then I restarted my PC. And my PC is still making noise ...

When in CLI I run this **nvidia-settings** I have this error:

```
ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded
ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system
(nvidia-settings:2563): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 14:48:03.768: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 14:48:03.770: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 14:48:03.770: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

When in CLI I run this **prime-select query** I have this:

```
nvidia
```

Any idea please? I'm looking in Google, but I can't find the solution, and it's a bit beyond my skills as a PHP developer.

Thank you very much.